When a wheel begins to roll on a flat surface, is it due to fulcrum generated at the contact point by friction?
[Edit: What I'm trying to understand is how any wheel rolls on a surface, instead of just spinning in place. I know that friction provides the force to make the wheel roll, but I'm unsure about the specifics of how this happens.]
As shown in the picture below, the dotted circle represents the gear responsible for transmitting the force generated by the engine to rotate the wheel, denoted as F1, F2, F3, F4, etc. P is the contact point. Friction prevents point P from moving, so the wheel can't spin. That creates many levers which have a fulcrum at point P. Here, I'm using F1 and F2 as examples. Imagine line AP as a lever. Since F1 equals F2, and the distance from F1 to point P is greater than the distance from F2 to point P, the lever will rotate around point P, thereby causing the wheel to move forward.
Is my explanation correct?

